# Why do I have multiple (unassociated) temporal history tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, temporal-tables

I have been setting up a proof of concept system which has a SQL Server 2017 back end.
The system uses temporal tables to record asset configurations and track changes over time.
I have a Data table which is linked to the history table, let's call it dbo.MSSQL_TemporaryHistoryFor_12345678900.

So far so good. I have two issues:

Today I turned off versioning on the table so I could add a computed column. This was done and turned back on again without errors.

Now I find that I cannot query any historic data from before the change. New data is being added to the history, but there is nothing beforehand.

Looking inside SSMS, I can now see there are multiple history tables, all with the same name but with a hex suffix, e.g. dbo.MSSQL_TemporaryHistoryFor_12345678900_A0B1C2D3. They are not linked beneath the main data table. They are just floating around on their own inside the database. When I queried sys.tables, these are not shown as history tables and are not linked to the main data table.

These tables do contain the historical data which is missing.

The questions I have are therefore:

- What do these additional tables represent?
- How were they created?
- Is there any way to somehow relink these into the main history chain so I can get my historical reporting back?

It's very frustrating so any help you can provide would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide the commands you ran before you got into this state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *need* to provide the name of the history table in order to maintain data continuity when turning system versioning off and on.  This behavior is mentioned in the documentation for [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If you don't use the HISTORY_TABLE argument, the system generates a new history table matching the schema of the current table, creates a link between the two tables, and enables the system to record the history of each record in the current table in the history table.

Here's a demo.  I'll create the example table from the documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee   
(    
  [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
  , [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL  
  , [Position] varchar(100) NOT NULL   
  , [Department] varchar(100) NOT NULL  
  , [Address] nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL  
  , [AnnualSalary] decimal (10,2) NOT NULL  
  , [ValidFrom] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  
  , [ValidTo] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END  
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)  
 )    
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

This results in a history table named `MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_1253579504`.  Now I'll disable and enable system versioning:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

And I'm in your exact situation:

[image]

---

Now I'll clean everything up:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
DROP TABLE dbo.MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_1253579504;
DROP TABLE dbo.MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_1253579504_D0055BB4;
```

Then create the table with a specific history table name:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee   
(    
  [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
  , [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL  
  , [Position] varchar(100) NOT NULL   
  , [Department] varchar(100) NOT NULL  
  , [Address] nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL  
  , [AnnualSalary] decimal (10,2) NOT NULL  
  , [ValidFrom] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  
  , [ValidTo] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END  
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)  
 )    
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
```

Then turn system versioning off and on, but continue specifying the history table name:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
```

*Note: in your specific situation, you should be able to use this syntax to "reattach" one lost history table to your base table*

No extra tables:

[image]

**The takeaway**

*Always* specify a history table name explicitly when creating temporal tables or enabling system versioning.

The MS docs now call this out specifically on the [Stopping System-Versioning on a System-Versioned Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-2017) page:

> When turning system versioning back on, do not forget to specify the HISTORY_TABLE argument. Failing to do so will result in a new history table being created and associated with the current table. The original history table will still exist as a normal table, but won't be associated with the current table.